# What Is the "Standard" Shulchan Aruch Page Based On? How Many Dapim Are There?

Tags: history, jewish-books, shulchan-aruch, writing-printing, statistics

There are many editions of the Shulchan Aruch and they do not all follow the same pagination. However, many editions I have seen call themselves "tzurat hadaf" and appear to have a similar layout and page density as each other. I have several questions about this purportedly standard layout:

1. How standardized is this layout? Do different tzurat hadaf editions begin and end each page with the same word in the same way printed Gemaras have since Bomburg? Do they have the same layout of the main mefarshim (e.g, Magen Avraham, Shakhm and Taz) in the way all Vilna Talmud's do?
2. What is the standard layout based on? Is is modeled off a specific print edition in the same way almost gemaras on the market are based on the Vilna Shas?
3. Have smaller details about the page changed over time? For example, in the Vilna Shas my understanding is that Rashi and Tosaafot have not moved but some editions change marginal notes, "extras" like musaf Rashi, move around cross-citations like the Torah Ohr, etc.). Has that happend with the Shulchan Aruch? Some of the "standard" commentaries like Levushei Srad, Yad Avraham, and Rabbi Akiva Eger are "only" 200 years old, so I'm wondering if those got added later.
4. How many total pages are in these editions of the Shulchan Aruch (just the main text, not the extras in the back like the Pri Megadim, Eshel Avraham, etc.), which I assume change much more from edition to edition.

I cannot find answers to these questions on Google and I only have access to an incomplete set of older shulchan aruch and a complete set of a newer mehudar one, which doesn't adhere to tzurat hadaf and has a lot of extras.